# Installation of Ubuntu fails on my Dell latitude D630

Tags: installation, laptop, dell

I can boot the usb live Ubuntu 12.04, but when I try to launch the installation program from the desktop nothing happen.
I don't know how to proceed to check what is going on but I also tried to use the system monitor and everything works except when i click on the "system" tab, in this case the monitor stops and disappears.

Does anyone know the solution for this issue ?

Is ubuntu compatible with Dell lattitude laptops?

Comment: You say you can boot from USB, but you want to launch fro the desktop.  How are you trying to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I boot whith a live usb drive which has worked already to install 2 other desktops.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some problem with the ISO image you downloaded. Please compare the md5sum of the image you have with the checksum provided on the server.

To do this:

1. Note down the md5sum from the Ubuntu which you can find on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/dvd/20120811/.
2. Calculate the md5sum of the iso image you downloaded using the command `md5sum filename.iso` where filename.iso is your image file.
3. Compare the two sums.

If the checksums are same, you might want to check out the installation instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop.

To know more about checksums, check out the wikipedia article on Checksums.

You can also compare the sha1sum or sha256sum.

Comment: I already setup two other machines with this key.